# Does the new xcode crash due to running out of memory?

Tags: xcode4.5

I recently often get this:

```
Process:         Xcode [30248]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.5 (1839)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1839000000000000~3
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 10747437
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [140]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-10-09 10:32:37.454 +0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          136816 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           2
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  134365 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      1CBC3344-3A0F-4006-F51E-8FF9902D7CC5

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G182
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSMallocException): Out of memory. We suggest restarting the application. If you have an unsaved document, create a backup copy in Finder, then try to save.
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff93d7308e __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff96bd13f0 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff8b3ff914 ___NSInitializePlatform_block_invoke_0 (in Foundation)
  3  0x00007fff93ce7fe0 __CFStringChangeSizeMultiple (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff93d0d722 CFStringReplaceAll (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff93d0bd55 _CFBundleTryOnePreferredLprojNameInDirectory (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x00007fff93d0b3a0 _CFBundleAddPreferredLprojNamesInDirectory (in CoreFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff93d0ba7e _CFBundleGetLanguageSearchList (in CoreFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff93dbcf99 _CFBundleCreateQueryTableAtPath (in CoreFoundation)
  9  0x00007fff93db9817 _CFBundleCopyQueryTable (in CoreFoundation)
 10  0x00007fff93dbdeb9 _CFBundleCopyURLsOfKey (in CoreFoundation)
 11  0x00007fff93dbb3ad _CFBundleCopyFindResources (in CoreFoundation)
 12  0x00007fff93d1b757 CFBundleCopyResourceURL (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x00007fff907b4165 MTUOpenResourceFile (in SpeechSynthesis)
 14  0x00007fff907b40a7 MTUReadResourceDataFile (in SpeechSynthesis)
 15  0x00007fff907b3c1f ReadVoiceDescriptionFileFromBundle(__CFBundle*, VoiceDescription*) (in SpeechSynthesis)
 16  0x00007fff907b3a41 RegisterVoiceBundle(VoiceListRec**, SpeechEngine*, __CFBundle*, int) (in SpeechSynthesis)
 17  0x00007fff907b392f RegisterVoices(int, SpeechEngine*, VoiceListRec**) (in SpeechSynthesis)
 18  0x00007fff907b355f RebuildVoiceList(SpeechEngine*, VoiceListRec**) (in SpeechSynthesis)
 19  0x00007fff907afd4d RebuildVoiceListIfNecessary() (in SpeechSynthesis)
 20  0x00007fff907b01e6 NewSpeechChannel (in SpeechSynthesis)
 21  0x00007fff907b9e99 StartSpeakingNow (in SpeechSynthesis)
 22  0x00007fff93d2fda4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 23  0x00007fff93d2f8bd __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 24  0x00007fff93d15099 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 25  0x00007fff93d146b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 26  0x00007fff924640a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 27  0x00007fff92463e42 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 28  0x00007fff92463cd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 29  0x00007fff94ea4613 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff94ea3ed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff94e9b283 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 32  0x00007fff94e3fcb6 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 33  0x000000010080bd17 (in Xcode)
 34  0x000000010080bca8 (in Xcode)
```

The amount of memory is abundant. 8GB and there are still plenty left. Not to mention virtual memory. I am not sure if I should ask this to superuser.

The xcode version is Version 4.5 (4G182)

Did I set things up incorrectly or is this just a bug in xcode 4.5?

Should this be asked at superuser.com instead (but most of the crowd there probably do not use xcode).

Quite often when I change tabs, xcode will slow down.

Comment: I see there's an update available, to version 4.5.1, which as usual contains "bug fixes and stability improvements".

Comment: Since "upgrading" to 4.5.2, I'm on at least one force-close of X-Code per day. I have no idea what has changed to cause the problem, other than it seems more likely to happen if I have two projects open at once.
Previous versions seemed quite happy to have two or more projects open at a time. 4.5.2 will often become unresponsive and need a force-quit. I have 8GB RAM too.

Comment: Just found another quirk:
I had about half a dozen lines of code with multiple errors, which was commented out.
I selected it, uncommented it and X-code displayed several little red flags, as expected.
I re-commented it out, tried to build and run: fail, errors still highlighted, `//` completely ignored. I then had to individually select each line, uncomment it and then comment it out again before the code would build. Not a particularly helpful 'feature'.